# Hinding system folder in File Picker

Tags: android, filepicker

Question :- This code is working well for picking up the file but i want to hide system folders when I am running this code it also show me all android folder starting with "." I tried some things which you can already see in comments in my code..

FileChooser.java

```
package com.sarita.scheduler;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FileChooser extends ListActivity {

    private File currentDir;
    private FileArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        currentDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        fill(currentDir); 
    }
    private void fill(File f)
    {
        String rootDriectory =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName(); ;

/*      String chkFileName = f.getName().toString();
        String chkSystemFolder =String.valueOf(chkFileName.charAt(0));
        */
        File[]dirs = f.listFiles(); 
        /*if (chkSystemFolder != "."){*/
         this.setTitle("Current Dir: "+f.getName());
         List<Item>dir = new ArrayList<Item>();
         List<Item>fls = new ArrayList<Item>();
         try{



             for(File ff: dirs)
             { 
                Date lastModDate = new Date(ff.lastModified()); 
                DateFormat formater = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
                String date_modify = formater.format(lastModDate);
                if(ff.isDirectory()){


                    File[] fbuf = ff.listFiles(); 
                    int buf = 0;
                    if(fbuf != null){ 
                        buf = fbuf.length;
                    } 
                    else buf = 0; 
                    String num_item = String.valueOf(buf);
                    if(buf == 0) num_item = num_item + " item";
                    else num_item = num_item + " items";

                    //String formated = lastModDate.toString();
                    dir.add(new Item(ff.getName(),num_item,date_modify,ff.getAbsolutePath(),"directory_icon")); 
                }
                else
                {

                    fls.add(new Item(ff.getName(),ff.length() + " Byte", date_modify, ff.getAbsolutePath(),"file_icon"));
                }
             }

         }catch(Exception e)
         {    

         }

         Collections.sort(dir);
         Collections.sort(fls);
         dir.addAll(fls);
         if(!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(rootDriectory))
             dir.add(0,new Item("..","Parent Directory","",f.getParent(),"directory_up"));
         adapter = new FileArrayAdapter(FileChooser.this,R.layout.file_explorer,dir);
         this.setListAdapter(adapter); 
        /*}*/
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Item o = adapter.getItem(position);
        if(o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_icon")||o.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("directory_up")){
                currentDir = new File(o.getPath());
                fill(currentDir);
        }
        else
        {
            onFileClick(o);
        }
    }
    private void onFileClick(Item o)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Folder Clicked: "+ currentDir, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("GetPath",currentDir.toString());
        intent.putExtra("GetFileName",o.getName());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

FileArrayAdapter.java

```
package com.sarita.scheduler;

import java.util.List; 

import android.content.Context; 
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView; 
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{

    private Context c;
    private int id;
    private List<Item>items;

    public FileArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Item> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        c = context;
        id = textViewResourceId;
        items = objects;
    }
    public Item getItem(int i)
     {
         return items.get(i);
     }
     @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       final Item o = items.get(position);
       String chkFileName = o.getName().toString();
       String chkSystemFolder =String.valueOf(chkFileName.charAt(0));


               View v = convertView;
               if (v == null) 
               {
                   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                   v = vi.inflate(id, null);
               }

             /* create a new view of my layout and inflate it in the row */
            //convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );

               if (chkSystemFolder != ".")
               {        
               if (o != null) 
               {
                       TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                       TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
                       TextView t3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextViewDate);
                       /* Take the ImageView from layout and set the city's image */
                        ImageView imageCity = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fd_Icon1);
                        String uri = "drawable/" + o.getImage();
                        int imageResource = c.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, c.getPackageName());
                        Drawable image = c.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                        imageCity.setImageDrawable(image);
                     if (chkSystemFolder != "."){
                       if(t1!=null)
                        t1.setText(o.getName());
                       if(t2!=null)
                            t2.setText(o.getData());
                       if(t3!=null)
                            t3.setText(o.getDate());
                     }
                   }

       }

       return v;
       }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps the `File#isHidden()` method is what you're looking for?

Comment: I DOnt want to show the systemfiles and folders in my file picker.. This code allows me to pick the file but it also shows me the systemfolders of android which are starting from "."(dot) which i want to hide from the user

Comment: Then, I don't understand what the problem is. If you don't want to show a file/folder, don't add it to your list.

Comment: Means I dint get you?? I already tried this 
`chkSystemFolder =String.valueOf(chkFileName.charAt(0));
if(chkSystemFolder != ".")`

Comment: Thats somewhere i m going wrong i know I m just not getting where to add this code which result me to what i need

Comment: Add the following as the first line in the `for` loop in your `fill()` method: `if(ff.isHidden()) continue;`

Comment: You mean like this?
`for(File ff: dirs)
     
    { 
    if(ff.isHidden()) continue;
    Date lastModDate = new Date(ff.lastModified()); 
    DateFormat formater = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();`

Comment: I dont know why but u r code really helps me ty so much :)

Comment: I'll put the explanation in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following as the first line in the `for` loop of your `fill()` method:

```
 if(ff.isHidden()) continue;
```

The `File#isHidden()` returns `true` if the file or folder it represents is hidden; i.e. if its filename starts with `'.'`. The `continue` statement inside a loop causes the current iteration of the loop to be skipped. So, this code basically says "If this file/folder is hidden, just go to the next one."

Comment: OR, you could save a continue instruction (optimized performances), by checking **if not is hidden**. Anyway +1, you're on the right path.

Comment: I don't know about compiler optimizations. I do all my optimizations **before** the compiler intervention. Adding a instruction, in my opinion, slows the process. Since you can avoid that, why adding it? I'd use the **negation** to execute the code - same result, but faster.

Comment: Well, a negation is a boolean comparison, which I think is faster than      performing an action. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Post your results, I'm curious too!

Comment: Please do! Can't stand in my pants. ;)

Comment: Ok, so my manual optimization is the same as the compiler's one. I start doubting I'm human. ;)

Comment: I'll verify over a significant amount of iterations, let's say 100k.